# Using Slack API from Python

Tags: python, slack-api

I am following the following tutorial [Slack API tutorial](https://github.com/slackapi/python-slackclient) to post a message on slack. I already created  Slack application and was able to use it with Incoming Webhooks now I would like to use API from python. So I tried:

```
import os
from slackclient import SlackClient
slack_token = 'xoxp-long-sequence-of-numbers'
sc = SlackClient(slack_token)

sc.api_call(
  "chat.postMessage",
  channel="my_test_channel",
  text="Hello from Python! :tada:"
)
```

I got back the following error message:

```
    {'error': 'missing_scope',
 'headers': {'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'slack-route, x-slack-version-ts',
  'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
  'Access-Control-Expose-Headers': 'x-slack-req-id',
  'Cache-Control': 'private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate',
  'Connection': 'keep-alive',
  'Content-Encoding': 'gzip',
  'Content-Length': '105',
  'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
  'Date': 'Fri, 05 Apr 2019 17:07:06 GMT',
  'Expires': 'Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT',
  'Pragma': 'no-cache',
  'Referrer-Policy': 'no-referrer',
  'Server': 'Apache',
  'Strict-Transport-Security': 'max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload',
  'Vary': 'Accept-Encoding',
  'Via': '1.1 6529456e34a07353ab1987432f192696.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)',
  'X-Accepted-OAuth-Scopes': 'chat:write:user',
  'X-Amz-Cf-Id': 'wunHQVQpZicf-ynJO2u_n6CAQEGlYBH67ysu0fP1mfTEt86rRiAbrw==',
  'X-Cache': 'Miss from cloudfront',
  'X-Content-Type-Options': 'nosniff',
  'X-OAuth-Scopes': 'identify,incoming-webhook',
  'X-Slack-Req-Id': '990760fb-b110-43a1-86cb-fd4f8e2e34fa',
  'X-Via': 'haproxy-www-km3w',
  'X-XSS-Protection': '0'},
 'needed': 'chat:write:user',
 'ok': False,
 'provided': 'identify,incoming-webhook'}
```

My channel name is literally: `my_test_channel`. Probably I need to use different name, but how can I find it out?

**UPDATE**

So I found out encoded channel id and changed my script to:

```
import os
    from slackclient import SlackClient
    slack_token = 'xoxp-long-sequence-of-numbers'
    sc = SlackClient(slack_token)

    sc.api_call(
      "chat.postMessage",
      channel="CHXXXXXXX",
      text="Hello from Python! :tada:"
    )
```

but error back is still `missing scope`

Comment: is `my_test_channel` private or public? (is there a lock next to it in your slack or a hashtag) In my experience the slack python api hasn't been able to talk to private channels

Comment: @RichardStoeffel. It is public, there is no lock. There is hashtag `#my_test_channel`

Comment: how do you get slack-token of your own channel ?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like its missing the user option according to the error ('needed': 'chat:write:user'):

```
    sc.api_call(
      "chat.postMessage",
      channel="my_test_channel",
      text="Hello from Python! :tada:"
      user="U0XXXXXXX"
    )
```

Comment: I tried myself as user, but got the same error back `missing_scope`.

Comment: do you have the error provided when adding user? it should say which scope is missing.

Comment: the error is identical to one posted in main post, except time stamp is different

Comment: ok, it looks like  you don't have the permission, scope needed is 'chat:write:user', which the error says you are missing.

Comment: makes sense, I created bot for my application and got new slack_token for it. Token starts with `xoxb-....` and everything worked.

Comment: great - can you "accept" this answer please?